# C++ Derived Classes - Calling a virtual function from the parent class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm relatively new to writing large packages in C++, and as such am not totally familiar with some of the OOP techniques in the language.

I am working on a code that can run simulations to calculate the deformation of a material within the framework of various models. I have an overarching `Sim` class with methods such as `set_boundary_conditions()`, `update_grid()`, `solve()`, etc.

I would like to implement various models as derived classes. For example, I will have an `ElasticSim` class which derives from `Sim` if you would only like to consider the equations of linear elasticity, `PlasticSim` for plasticity, etc. etc.

Because the model defines the equations that must be solved, which comes into the `update_grid()` function, I have made `update_grid()` `virtual` so that it can be implemented differently for each model. Furthermore, `set_boundary_conditions()` is even more specific - different simulations within a given model will have different boundary conditions, so this should be `virtual` both in `Sim` and in any derived class. There will be *another* derived class which implements the boundary conditions for a given physical situation.

This may be overly complicated, but I think it is a very modular and versatile way to approach this problem. But I digress. I have one major question.

First, the `solve()` method is going to be identical for every model. Hence, I would like to define it in `Sim`. However, it calls `virtual` functions that will later be implemented by derived classes. Namely, in a bastardization of pseudocode and c++:

```
Sim::set_boundary_conditions()
for every time step...
    Sim::update_grid()
```

There will be quite a lot of coding before I can actually test this properly, and I have been unable to find a proper answer online. Does this actually make sense? In particular, I am calling `Sim::update_grid()` and `Sim::set_boundary_conditions()`, despite the fact that these functions will actually be implemented in a derived class and a derived class of a derived class respectively.

Comment: What you seem to be asking for is basic polymorphic programming and the only thing you have wrong is the syntax `Sim::update_grid()`.  That is used when you don't want polymorphic.  Leave out the `Sim::` when making a polymorphic call.

Comment: `solve()` would be a member function of `Sim` so there is a current object `*this` which might have some other run time type.  When you call `update_grid()` etc. within that, you get the right version (so long as `update_grid()` was declared `virtual`)

Comment: @JSF - yeah, you're probably right about that. I don't need the `Sim::update_grid()`? but if `update_grid()` is declared in `sim.h` and I'm calling it from `sim.cpp`, don't I need to specify where the function comes from? Like how when you `#include <iostream>` you need to either `std::cin` or `using std::cin`?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood.  I didn't give any opinion on whether you need to define `Sim::update_grid`.  I was just saying not to specify `Sim::` when **calling** it.  'std::` is a namespace, not a class.  More importantly you are using `cin` from elsewhere, while you seem to have said you will use `update_grid` from inside a function of `Sim`

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm saying that `sim.cpp` includes `sim.h` where `update_grid` is defined. So if I do not preface it with `Sim::`, will the compiler not complain about a lack of declaration? If not, I do not see why `using std::cin` is necessary to avoid `std::cin` in favor of `cin` when using `iostream`.

Comment: @laplacian13 `JSF` was merely pointing out that you have a syntactical issue in your (I assume) pseudocode. Instead of `Sim::update_grid()`, you should have `sim.update_grid()` or `sim->upgrade_grid()` (where `sim` is an instance of `Sim` or pointer/reference to one). That is, unless your `update_grid` was a static method (in which case it is not here). It was just about that little pseudocode you posted and not about the syntax for defining methods outside a class in a cpp file, e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this actually make sense?

Yes, and that's perfectly fine for `Sim::solve` to be non-virtual and call virtual functions. Only cases where you have to watch out for virtual calls is in constructors and destructors (because the vtable may yet be fully formed or may already be destroyed).

An idiom that might be useful to you at some point is NVI (non-virtual interface). The idea consists of using non-virtual methods for public interfaces and virtual methods for protected/private methods. The idea is to allow central control but still allow overridability of certain parts. Example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    // public non-virtual interface: calls virtual interface.
    void do_something()
    {
        // Can add central stuff here that affects the 
        // entire hierarchy at any given time.
        do_something_impl();
    }

private:
    // subclasses can override this part.
    virtual void do_something_impl() = 0;
};
```

This kind of design leaves wiggle room to do something centrally applicable to the entire hierarchy (in foresight or in hindsight) while allowing subclasses to partially-override the behavior and lead to new sub-branches of code.

Yet what you have with this central `sim` method defined in your base class calling virtual methods is fine. That would make it into an abstract base class mixing concrete implementation and overridable interfaces rather than a pure virtual interface devoid of any concrete implementation, e.g. In the same sense, it's worth noting that you can provide default implementations for virtual functions -- not all methods in your base class need to be pure virtuals, or even virtual functions at all.